# What are the suggested characteristics of an Astral Drifter from the Astral Adventurer's Guide?

Tags: dnd-5e, background

What are the suggested characteristics (Person, Ideals, Bonds, Flaws) of an Astral Drifter from the *Astral Adventurer's Guide* (in *Spelljammer: Adventures in Space*)?

Are there any, or a suggested set from another background?

Answer (score 8):

### There are no suggested characteristics for Astral Drifter

There are no personality traits, ideals, flaws or bonds for the backgrounds from *Astral Adventurer's Guide*, nor recommended ones to take from some other background.

Instead, for the two backgrounds presented (Astral Drifter and Wildspacer), some other features can serve as an inspiration for roleplaying the character. For [Wildspacer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/backgrounds/wildspacer), it's Close Encounter; in the case of [Astral Drifter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/backgrounds/astral-drifter), you have the Divine Contact feature:

> In the Astral Sea, you crossed paths with a wandering deity. The encounter was brief and nonviolent, yet it made a lasting impression on you. This deity saw fit to share one secret or obscure bit of cosmic lore with you. Work with your DM to determine the details of this knowledge and its impact on the campaign.
>
> Roll on the Divine Contact table to determine which deity you encountered, or work with your DM to identify a more suitable choice. [A table of Deities follows]

It's not the same thing, of course.

Your question is understandable, as this is a bit unusual; but there are other publications that lack the full set of four classical personality traits - for example, *Strixhaven: Curriculum of Chaos*  or *Dragonlance: Shadow of the Dragon Queen* backgrounds do not have them either, and instead provide trinket tables as roleplaying aids.

Answer (score 1):

There are no suggested characteristics for backgrounds from AAG, nor there are any suggestions to use them from another background, as far as I know.

Comment: +1. This is the correct, as far as I can tell. I posted another answer with a bit more background for the querant, as this is so brief, but that does not detract from it.